# Advice on building some African styled names?

Tags: culture, names

So in my little fantasy setting I got a fairly large and long standing dragon run empire. One of the cornerstones of its power is families of dragonbloods, humans with a dragon in their bloodline (the dragons can shapeshift if you were wondering…), who in exchange for loyalty to said dragon gain considerable political power. Due to the fact there own standing is often directly linked to the dragon, they use the dragons name as part of their own name in a specific style.

For example if a dragon is called Ra, then his distant great great great (a few times) grandson might be called John of the Ra Blessed Line of Smith. Further complicating things is the ‘Ra Blessed Line of Smith’ bit will always take dominance in wedding partner's and children’s naming, regardless if it’s John or Jane whose getting married, so as you can expect this means in practice there’s going to be -a lot- of Ra Blessed Line of Smith’s after a few generations!

Now the problem is I’ve run into is I want to have bunch of dragonblood families who serve a dragon who settled into a place with a rather African feel to it over a thousand years ago. And I’ve come to realise from a little bit of light research that Western styled surnames aren’t really an African thing, especially since I’m trying to avoid any Colonial or Arabic influences in the character naming traditions.

So I was wondering if there anything I could use instead for the ‘Smith’ part that would fit with a bunch of families incredibly keen to tell the world there part of the same bloodline?

Comment: Why doesn't [this](https://adoption.com/baby-names/origin/african) work? (First hit on google for "most common African names)

Comment: The problem with that is, if you just copy and past things from a living culture, sometimes that culture can take issue with the job.  You remember when Moana came out and the Maui Halloween costume was pulled from the shelves because real Polynesians were deeply offended?  Same kind of thing we want to avoid here.

Comment: "African" is probably way too broad. There are thousands of native languages and ethnic groups in Africa

Comment: The idea of an "African styled name" implies a failure to comprehend the scale of Africa. Africa is BIG. It's about three times the size of Europe and is home to 2000+ different languages. There are no African names. There are Hausa names and Xhosa names and Maasai names, etc.

Comment: I would expect there will be name variations based upon which language family is being spoken, and Africa has higher variation of language then almost all other continents. Look up language family maps. I know patronymics is/was common in many regions. ie John son of Mohammad.  but  again how that is formulated will depend on the local language.

Comment: Whatever you do, if your work is successful, some people will be offended. Or they will make pretend that they are offended. Or some do gooders will cry that some unspecified people are offended. So go ahead and feel free to use the names of African emperors and kings and queens. They are long dead anyway, and the states they ruled are all gone to dust. I recommend the rulers of [Meroë](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meroë) (aka [Kush](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_monarchs_of_Kush)), as nobody can seriously claim to be a successor. Natakamani (m), Amanitore (f), Malonaqen (m)...

Comment: This may be the closest I've seen to an on topic question about what to name something. However you're still wanting to make up a name and as such this question is POB.

Comment: Isn't this question about "writing" more than "worldbuilding"?

Comment: Regarding your question/names tag. in the description of the tag: "This tag is NOT to be used to ask questions of the form "what is the best name...?" which are off-topic. ".  Obviously your question is not about the best name for ONE person but follows more this excerpt "Questions with this tag seek help where the use of a name affects a rule or system of their world. " I disagree with the VTC's on principle because it isn't about naming a singular thing but, a world's system for naming which he wants to be close to an existing set of cultures. Individual = VTC, System = Valid Worldbuilding

Answer (score 5):

Africa, like Asia (or even Europe & America) are pretty big places with lots of possibilities for dragons. And naming customs.

A couple possibles are Kirimu a dragon from Nyanga mythology and Arwe, the serpent king of Ethiopia who was defeated by a hero who became the progenitor of the Solomonic emperors of that country. There are also dragons and dragon slayers in southern Africa. Look into the legend of Thakane.

As for naming conventions, they're every bit as varied as customs elsewhere in the world. In Ethiopia for example, one has a given name and then a patronymic (and then possibly an avonymic).

Perhaps there could be several competing dragon blessed lines. Perhaps you could combine systems, like Jane of the Ra blessed Smith Johnsdaughter.

A good trawl through the [Font of All Knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patronymic) will prove beneficial as you move from light research to shallow research in these topics.